# How to ignore extra fields in create jira api request payload?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am doing Jira integration in my application. Different issueType(like Story/Task/Support Incident) have a different set of fields to be added to create an issue of the given issueType.

I got a common POJO having fields for all types of issues. When I hit Jira API to create issue of type Story, it fails saying fields (which are required for issueType Support Incident) are not available on the screen.

```
{
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "key1": "Field 'key1' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
        "key2": "Field 'key2' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
        "customfield_10216": "Field 'customfield_10216' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
        "customfield_21263": "Field 'customfield_21263' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
        "customfield_10704": "Field 'customfield_10704' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
        "customfield_10212": "Field 'customfield_10212' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
    }
}
```

How can we ignore the unknown fields in Jira APIs?

Answer (score 0):

since you are creating an issue, I assume, you have to add the custom fields to your issue creation screen.

Have a look at your project settings and there on the screens:

( http:///plugins/servlet/project-config//screens )

Then open the screen that is used for creating an issue. Look at the URL. There you can see the screenId.

In that form, you can also add your custom fields to the screen.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/quot-Field-customfield-10012-cannot-be-set-It-is-not-on-the/qaq-p/664236

Comment: I have an idea about custom fields. Let me explain my question: 
Let's say there are 2 types of issues: 'Story' and 'Support Ticket'. 
*Story issue has 4 fields to set which are F1, F2, F3, and F4 
*Support Ticket issue has 5 fields to set which are F1, F2, F4, F5, and F6

I added a POJO which has 6 fields: F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, and F6.

Now when I hit jira create issue API for issueType 'Story', it fails saying: F5 and F6 cannot be set and it is not on appropriate screen or unknown.